# Batch file that keeps the x latest files in a specific folder

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

How can you specify a specific folder? for instance in "c:\temp with spaces"?

this command works, but only in the same folder as where it is executed:

```
for /f "skip=7 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d *.txt') do @del "%%F"
```

But how can i specify a certain folder? This is not working:

```
for /f "skip=3 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d "c:\temp\ with spaces*.txt"') do @del "%%F"
```

it seeks for the txt files in the current directory, and if the .bat file is in another folder, it does not work

help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why `eol=:`? It seems superfluous.

Comment: @wOxxOm, the `;` (default `eol`) is a valid file name character. It is needed if you have files with names starting with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change to the desired folder

```dos
pushd "x:\some folder\with\files" && (
    for /f "skip=7 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d *.txt') do @del "%%F"
    popd
)
```

Comment: Great! that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by running manually `dir /b` without specifying `/s` lists only the filenames without the full path so `@del "%%F"` tries to remove the file from current folder.

Simply specify the full path in `del` too:

```
@del "c:\temp\%%F"
```